# postgresql sub query has too many columns when checking against in condition

Tags: postgresql

Here is my query:

```
SELECT * FROM table1
WHERE col1 IN (SELECT cola, colb, colc, cold FROM table2)
```

where all cols are of data type `integer`. When I execute this query I get "sub query has too many columns". What whould be the right way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM table1
WHERE col1 = ANY (
                    (SELECT array_agg(ARRAY[cola, colb, colc, cold])
                        FROM a
                    )::integer[]
                 );
```